# My account is disabled on Facebook, will a second copy of it be kept on the server?

Tags: facebook, account-management

My account is stated as disabled, will my account still be able to  be re-enabled with existing information when I reach 13 this year June or do I need to re-create a new Facebook account?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure Facebook disabled your account for being less than 13 years old. Hmm, they should have sent a notification on your email, if you have got one they will provide links to pages where you might get further help.

And as for keeping a copy on server, it depends on why they disabled your account. Most of the accounts get disabled for posting spams and their profile is kept on their server for a very short time, they would delete it once they review the case and found the profile to be  violating. But Facebook handle accounts very carelessly, so you can only hope to regain access to your account, but you may try once, if they decline the request, create a new account, it's free at last !